# WCF "Content Type was not supported" error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-client

When I am trying to connect to my WCFService the following error occurred.

> Content Type text/xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service
>   http://localhost:1978/Service1.svc.  The client and service bindings
>   may be mismatched.

My service code is :

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(string fName, string lName);
    }
}
```

And in the client form I am calling this service as follows:

```
endPointAddr = "http://localhost:1978/Service1.svc";

BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
httpBinding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;

EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(endPointAddr);

Append("Attempt to connect to: " + endPointAddr);

IService1 proxy = ChannelFactory<IService1>.CreateChannel(httpBinding, endpointAddress);

using (proxy as IDisposable)
{
    string strNew=proxy.GetData(textBox2.Text, textBox1.Text) ;
}
```

I am stuck on that error, if anybody knows please help.

Comment: What is your service's config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your WCF service has a binding of `WSHttpBinding` or similar - you need to change the client binding (which is currently using `BasicHttpBinding`) accordingly to make it work...